# How to use the array value previously used in an if statement?

Tags: c#, arrays

This might be the wrong way to go about it but I'm trying to call a specific number from an array, the number will change depending on which "if" statement was used. For example

```
if (diameter >= constDiameter[0] && diameter < constDiameter[1])                 
{
    areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / constNumberOfSlices[0];                                                                
}
else if (diameter >= constDiameter[1] && diameter < constDiameter[2])            
{
    areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / constNumberOfSlices[1];             
}
else if (diameter >= constDiameter[2] && diameter < constDiameter[3])            
{
    areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / constNumberOfSlices[2];            
}
Console.WriteLine("A " + diameter + "\" pizza will yield {0} slices", constNumberOfSlices);
```

For "constNumberOfSlices I want it to print whichever number was actually used in the If statement.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put print statements inside the if/else if blocks.

Comment: You're going to have to save the value, somewhere, if you want to re-use it.

Comment: yea I was thinking in storing/saving the value in a diff int, but I was just making sure there wasn't a diff way cause my teacher is picky with having as little code as possible. Thanks tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a container to store the number of slices you have for your pizza. Let us know if this makes sense!

```
int constNumberOfSlices;
if (diameter >= constDiameter[0] && diameter < constDiameter[1])                 
{
    constNumberOfSlices = constNumberOfSlices[0];
    areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / constNumberOfSlices[0];                                                                
}
else if (diameter >= constDiameter[1] && diameter < constDiameter[2])            
{
   constNumberOfSlices = constNumberOfSlices[1];
   areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / constNumberOfSlices[1];             
}
else if (diameter >= constDiameter[2] && diameter < constDiameter[3])            
{
    constNumberOfSlices = constNumberOfSlices[2];
    areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / constNumberOfSlices[2];            
}

Console.WriteLine("A " + diameter + "\" pizza will yield {0} slices", constNumberOfSlices);
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you have to save it when it is found.

Also you can take advantage of the for loop in this scenario.

```
int slices = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    if (diameter >= constDiameter[i] && diameter < constDiameter[i + 1])                 
    {
        areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / constNumberOfSlices[i];
        slices = i;
        break;                                                  
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried something like this works perfect thanks for the idea

Comment: Careful with this method though, make sure you remember to change what `i` is if you increase the size of the array. Or better yet do `for (int i = 0; i < constDiameter.Count; i++)`

Comment: @JeffreyHaines True - I left that to him to figure out because I didn't know enough of how those arrays were initialized etc. Plus using constDiameter.Count would not work unless you did `(int i = 1; i <= constDiameter.Count; i++)` and then on the if statement did `if (diameter >= constDiameter[i - 1] && diameter < constDiameter[i])`

Comment: Two arrays are hard to remember to maintain. Maybe you want `List<Tuple<int, int>>` where the Ints are the value, and your list iterator will tell you which values to use.

Comment: Yeah it would work look at the numbers I used... Count returns the actual count.

Comment: `constDiameter[i + 1]` would throw an index out of range on the last iteration ;)

Comment: You have the same problem :P You assume constDiameter.Count always equals 3.

Comment: That's why I left it to him to figure out, simply because we don't know enough to provide a solid solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could print the number you're using from within the `if/else` block. However, since you're always doing the same computation anyway you might want to store the number of slices and then compute the area afterwards, like so:

```
int numberOfSlices;
if (diameter >= constDiameter[0] && diameter < constDiameter[1])                 
{
    numberOfSlices = constNumberOfSlices[0];                                                               
}
else if (diameter >= constDiameter[1] && diameter < constDiameter[2])            
{
    numberOfSlices = constNumberOfSlices[1];             
}
else if (diameter >= constDiameter[2] && diameter < constDiameter[3])            
{
    numberOfSlices = constNumberOfSlices[2];            
}
else
{
    // Put default value for number of slices here.
}
areaOfTheSlice = areaOfThePizza / numberOfSlices;
Console.WriteLine("A " + diameter + "\" pizza will yield {0} slices", numberOfSlices);
```

Note that you'll have to find a default value for the number of slices in case none of the conditions in the `if` blocks were true.